# How do I convert binary data from MySQL to a string in ColdFusion 11?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml

I have a field in my MySQL database that is set to data type "BIT". The value in the field is 101101. I am trying to read this value using Coldfusion (version 11)

I simply use the following code:

```
<cfquery name=q1 datasource=#data_source#>
  select * from mytable
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
 #q1.mybitfield#
</cfoutput>
```

I have tried using CAST and CONVERT on the MySQL side and I have tried CharSetEncodeing on the CF side along with every option of ToString, ToBase64, and ToBinary that I can think of.

I still can not get my output to look like it does in the database.

Comment: Edit: What is the output of the above? I cannot test right now but IIRC, mySQL's BIT fields are returned as numbers, so try the FormatBaseN function ie `FormatBaseN(q1.mybitfield, 2)` . Otherwise, dump the class name of the column ie q1.mybitfield.getClass().name. What is the result ?  Also, out of curiosity why do you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to give you credit for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I was probably thinking of SQL Server's bit type. For MySQL, a simpler option might be to use the [bin()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_bin) function which:

> Returns a string representation of the binary value of N, ...This is equivalent to CONV(N,10,2). Returns
>   NULL if N is NULL.

For example:

```
  SELECT  bin(YourBitColumn) AS YourBitColumn FROM YourTable
  ... or 
  SELECT  bin(YourBitColumn+0) AS YourBitColumn FROM YourTable
```

NB: *[High-order 0 bits are not displayed in the converted value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html)*. That applies the CF function as well.

Comment: This works also and seems a bit easier since it is all in one step. Thanks. I've been looking for this for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Leigh for your help. I was never able to get it to work with just one step so I used a two step solution (if you want to call it that). What I ended up doing was setting up my MySQL statement to convert the field to an Unsigned interger (although Decimal or a signed integer would have also worked), then once I read in the decimal value I was able to convert it to binary using your suggestion of FormatBaseN(q1.myfield,2). So thanks for the reminder of FormatBaseN. I had forgotten about that one.

My final code ended up looking like this:

The MySQL statement:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(item , UNSIGNED) as di from mytable
```

And the Coldfusion looked like this:

```
<cfset d = FormatBaseN(q1.di, 2)>
```

**Edit**

After writing this, I decided to go with Leigh's answer above since it was a better solution.

Comment: Actually, I was probably thinking of SQL Server in terms of return type. A quick search suggests you can use mysql's BIN() function. Try:  `SELECT BIN(item +0) AS di FROM yourTable`